# shinydashboard vs shinydashboardPlus - dashboardsidebar title differences

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

I have a Shiny app built with shinydashboard and I've just discovered shinydashboardPlus.  One nice option is to have the sidebarMenu "minified", or when minimized it doesn't go away completely, but just displays the icons for each menuItem.  However, with shinydashboardPlus, when minified, the title gets chopped off.  With shinydashboard, the title stays intact, but the sidebar goes away completely.

Example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
#library(shinydashboardPlus)

# Basic dashboard page template
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
    dashboardSidebar(#minified = TRUE,
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem('Menu1', tabName = 'Menu1', 
                 icon = icon('folder-open')),
        menuItem('Menu2', tabName = 'Menu2',
                 icon = icon('code-branch'))
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody()
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Leaving the comment marks in place and running it uses shinydashboard, and gives this initially:

[image]

And when the hamburger is clicked to minimize the sidebar, the whole sidebar disappears:

[image]

If the comment marks are removed so that it runs using shinydashboardPlus, minimizing it gives this, where I have the icons in the sidebar, but the title is chopped:

[image]

Is there a way to get the shinydashboardPlus minification that shows just the icons, but doesn't chop off the title?

Comment: What do you mean "but doesn't chop off the title"? Not showing the title at all or change the title to a smaller font size so it still shows it? You understand if you collapse, there is not enough space to show the original text right?

Comment: If you run the code, you'll see that when you minimize with shinydashboard, the title does not change - it doesn't get chopped or clipped but remains displayed.  But when you minimize with shinydashboardPlus, the title get clipped.  Essentially the right boundary follows the minimization of the navigation pane below it.  I would like the title to stay as it is before minimization but the navigation pane below it to shrink to only display icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

# Basic dashboard page template
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
    dashboardSidebar(#minified = TRUE,
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem('Menu1', tabName = 'Menu1', 
                 icon = icon('folder-open')),
        menuItem('Menu2', tabName = 'Menu2',
                 icon = icon('code-branch'))
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tags$style(
        '
        @media (min-width: 768px){
          .sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-header .logo {
              width: 230px; 
          }
          .sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-header .navbar {
              margin-left: 230px;
          }
        }
        '
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

change the `width` and `margin-left` numbers if you have extreme long titles.
[image]

Comment: Perfect!  I would never have figured that out on my own.  Thank you!!